# Stata: Unable to return Global Macro of Filename

Tags: global, stata

I am using `filelist` to generate a dataframe of each folder and the files contained in it. I would like to save each folder name and file name with an observation number x to be able to pull their names out later.

```
ssc install filelist
filelist

//Save each file's name and corresponding folder:
forvalues x = 1 / `=_N' {               //for every row in the filelist dataframe shown
    local file = filename[`x']
    global folder_`x' dirname[`x']      //save the folder name as folder_i, i = 1, 2, ... _N
    global file_`x' filename[`x']       //save the file name as file_i, i = 1, 2, ... _N
}
global filecount `=_N'
```

This runs smoothly, and if I was to run `di $file_2`, for instance, it would produce the given filename. The issue I have is that then when I try to use this and access these Globals later on, they appear to have saved the "filename[`x']" rather than the actual filename. For instance, if I run:

```
import excel "InterestRates.xlsx", sheet("US") firstrow 
di $file_2
```

Then I get the error `filename not found`. I have tried changing up my `' and "" and {} in many different ways, and I still cannot seem to get this to reference the actual filename. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the code from the point where `di $file_2` was still working up to the point that it gave you `"filename[\`x']"`? Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: It worked right before the ```import excel``` line. Forgot to add that there was a  ```clear``` command as well with the import.

Comment: Sorry, you need to show more code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for info on how best to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to assign local or global macros: with an equal sign, and without. If it is assigned without an equal sign, the content will be stored as it is. With an equal sign, the content will be evaluated first.

```
clear
input str8 filename
"file.dta"
end

global file_1 filename[1]
global file_2 = filename[1]

di "$file_1"
di "$file_2"
```

Result:

```
. di "$file_1"
filename[1]

. di "$file_2"
file.dta
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight alteration to Wouter's code which still gives me the error:

```
cd [MY_PATH_HERE]
ssc install filelist
filelist

//Save each file's name and corresponding folder:
forvalues x = 1 / `=_N' {               //for every row in the filelist dataframe shown
    local file = filename[`x']
    global folder_`x' dirname[`x']      //save the folder name as folder_i, i = 1, 2, ... _N
    global file_`x' filename[`x']       //save the file name as file_i, i = 1, 2, ... _N
}

export excel test.xlsx, firstrow(var) 
import excel different.xlsx, firstrow clear

di $file_1
```

This then still produces the `filename not found` error as before. It works fine when telling Stata to import the same Excel (`test.xlsx`) you just saved, but if you import a different Excel, it causes issues. I don't understand why this is the case though if you are saving it as a global macro.

Comment: What do you get when you change `di $file_1` to `di "$file_1"`?

Comment: In any case, `import excel` shouldn't affect macros so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: ```di "$file_1"``` produces ```filename[1]```. So it seems like it is saving the command rather than the output. In which case, you'd maybe want to use ```global file_`x' = filename[`x']``` within the for loop, but this still doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Actually, I am wrong on the above comment. Using the equal sign to assign the global works when you use ```di "$file_1"``` rather than ```di $file_1```. I think I can make it work then from here. Thanks Wouter!

Comment: Yes, you need the equal sign when assigning the macro, otherwise it's stored as a string. I overlooked that in my answer because the output was still okay, since the string was evaluated in the `display` command without quotes.